# Block Ui. js file is not working for the first time operation in Mozilla browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
```

here we are declared these .js files in our jsp page . this function is not working for the first time of the calling to the validate method.
we had added this  :default-applyPlatformOpacityRules attribute also.

and then we had tried with replacing this $.blockUI.defaults.applyPlatformOpacityRules = false,
 while loading the jsp function also.
But still we are facing the error.

```
 function validate() { 
        $.blockUI.defaults.applyPlatformOpacityRules =false
        $.blockUI({ 

           message: '<div ><img src="images/adminloading.gif " height="42" width="42"/>
            <h2 style = "color:#ffffff" >Please Wait.!</h2></div>',
            $.blockUI.defaults.applyPlatformOpacityRules = false,
                 /* overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#ffffff' },*/
               css: { 
                    border: 'none', 
                    padding: '15px', 
                     backgroundColor: 'none', 
                    '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
                    '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
                      opacity: 0.4, 
                     } 
                }); 
        }
```

Comment: You waited for the loading of page with $(document).ready before calling this validate function?